# Inverse function for $f(x)=x/(1-e^{-x})$

Tags: inverse-function, lambert-w

I'm looking for the inverse function for $f(x)=x/(1-e^{-x})$, over the domain $x>0$.

Wolfram says that the answer is $f^{-1}(x)=x+W(-xe^{-x})$, for $x>1$, where $W(x)$ is the Lambert W function. Graphically this looks correct, but I'm struggling to verify it for myself on paper. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide the working for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formulation uses $x$ for both for the variable in $f(x)$ and for the different variable in $f^{-1}(x)$, which may cause confusion. Let's instead describe this as solving $y =\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$ for $x$.

The Lambert W function provides the solution(s) to  $we^w =z$ with $w=W_n(z)$ which suggests here to get your desired solution you should be considering $z=-ye^{-y}$ and $w = x-y$.  We now need to manipulate the original equation into a suitable form:

- $y =\dfrac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$
- $x = y -ye^{-x}$
- $x -y = -ye^{-x}$
- $(x -y)e^{x-y} = -ye^{-y}$

which we can now solve using the Lambert W function as

- $x-y = W_n(-ye^{-y})$
- $x=y+W_n(-ye^{-y})$

and this is the desired solution as given by [Wolfram Alpha.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20y%3Dx%2F%281-exp%28-x%29%29)

Comment: Note that if $x>0$ then $y>1$.  Negative $x$ still works with your function so with $x<0$ then you would have $0<y<1$ while the inverse you would need to use there would be $W_{-1}$ rather than the principal branch $W_0$ - if you use the wrong branch then you will get $y+W_n(-ye^{-y}) =0$ which is usually not what you want as it is equivalent to considering $\frac00$ when $x=0$ in your original expression; looking at the limits on each side as $x \to 0$, you might also want to extend your function to say that when $x=0$ you get $y=1$ and vice-versa for the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

We use one of the both defining equations of the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions):

$$\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}=y$$

**1.) Elementary functions**

$$x-y+ye^{-x}=0$$

We see, this equation is a polynomial equation *of more than one* algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^{-x}$) *and with no univariate factor*. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation. See also Joseph Fels Ritt 1925.

$$xe^x-ye^x+y=0$$

We see, for algebraic $y$, this equation is an irreducible algebraic equation of both $x$ and $e^x$ simultaneously. Algebraic equations of this kind cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number). See Ferng-Ching Lin 1983 and Timothy Chow 1999.
The elementary function on the left-hand side of zeroing equations of this kind cannot have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#partial_inverses) that are elementary functions therefore.

**2.) Lambert W**

$$(y-x)e^x=y$$

We see, both the factor and the exponent of the exponential term are linear functions of the solution variable ($x$). Such equations can be solved in terms of Lambert W - as shown by the other answer.